# Problem with authentication system in PHP

Tags: php, authentication, session

I created a small project using PHP which there are about 50 users and each user has his own username and password and the main function of the users is writing a post.

A user opens the form page to write a post and after filling the form, click the ADD button.

In this case, The form action redirects to another page and inserts it into the database and then redirects to the home page which shows posts written by logged-in user.

The problem is that when redirecting the home page, the logged-in user sees another logged-in user's posts. This situation happens sometimes(not always).

Another interesting thing is that if the user clicks the F5 button in this case, then show his own posts again. I have been trying to solve this problem for nearly two months. But I cannot find the reason for the problem.

Can anyone help me?

**Note: I use SESSION for authentication!!!**

init.php:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
require_once("session.php");
define('DELETION_CONFIRM','onclick="return confirm(\'<<<Предупреждение>>> Вы уверены, что хотите удалить этот элемент?\');"');
define('PAYMENT_CONFIRM','onclick="return confirm(\'<<<Предупреждение>>> Вы уверены, что хотите изменить статус платежа?\');"');
define('SITE_NAME','http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('PAGE_NAME','http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('TOKEN','629625615:AAHBtdU7NzCtw92O1uSG7cu5_ydzCyZxaQ0');
define("GO_BACK_BUTTON", "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"goBack()\" class=\"btn btn-primary\"><i class=\"fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw\"></i> Hазад</button><script>function goBack(){window.history.back();}</script>");
$path_of_current_page=($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
$current_page=basename($path_of_current_page);
$blank_types_list=array("fcc_export"=>"ФСС ташқи", "fcc_local"=>"ФСС ички", "akd"=>"Раскредитовка/АКД", "fumigation"=>"Акт Фумигация");
require_once("db/database.php");
require_once("model/db_object.php");
require_once("model/user.php");
require_once("model/region.php");
require_once("model/country.php");
require_once("model/role.php");
require_once("model/district.php");
require_once("model/certificate_of_disinfestation.php");
require_once("model/fumigator.php");
require_once("model/fumigation_formula.php");
require_once("model/fumigation_insecticide.php");
require_once("model/fumigation_declaration.php");
require_once("model/disinfected_object.php");
require_once("model/insecticide_exchange.php");
require_once("model/blank_exchange.php");
require_once("model/fumigation_chamber.php");
require_once("model/inspector.php");
require_once("model/monthly_remainder_of_insecticide.php");
require_once("functions.php");
```

home.php

```
<?php
include("init.php");
$role="";  
if(strpos($_SESSION['role'],"region_fumigator")!==false){     
    $role=$_SESSION['role'];
  }else{     
    $role="";
  }
check_login($role);
$certificate_type=NULL;
$certificates_of_disinfestation_number=count($certificate_of_disinfestation_object->find_by_ids($_SESSION['user_id'],"registrar_id"));
$certificates_of_disinfestation=$certificate_of_disinfestation_object->find_by_ids_with_pagination($_SESSION['user_id'],"registrar_id",$offset,$number_of_records_per_page);
include("header.php");
?>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content"> 
        <div class="box-body">
        <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="background-color: white;">
          <?php 
            if(!empty($certificates_of_disinfestation)){
          ?>
          <div class="scrolled_table" >
            <table class="js-dynamitable table table-striped" style="min-width:3000px;">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th style="width: 70px;border-bottom: 1px solid #119769;">
                  </th>               
                  <th colspan="2" style="width:210px;">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspАФ &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
                  </th>               
                  <th colspan="2" style="width:500px;">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspТашкилот&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
                  </th>               
                  <th colspan="3" style="width:400px;">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspМаҳсулот &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
                  </th>
                  <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #119769;width:150px;">
                  </th>               
                  <th colspan="4" style="width:650px;">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Фумигант &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
                  </th>                                 
                  <th colspan="2" style="width:300px;">
                    &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspФумигант сумма 
                  </th>                               
                  <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #119769;"></th>
                  <th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #119769;"></th>
                  <th style="width:110px;border-bottom: 1px solid #119769;"></th>
                  <th style="width:90px;border-bottom: 1px solid #119769;"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th style="width: 70px;border-top:white;">№<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th> № <?=table_sort_icons();?></th>  
                  <th>САНАСИ<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>Номи <?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>ИНН<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>Номи<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>Miqdori<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>бирлиги<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>Давлат Hоми<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>Formulasi<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>Номи<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>норма(гр/мл) <?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>cарфланган(гр/мл)<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>1 m<sup>3</sup>/m<sup>2</sup> <?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th>жами<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                  <th><img src="printer.png" width=25></th>
                  <th><img src="envelope.png" width=25></th>
                  <th>Имп_Экс_Вын</th>
                  <th>АФ №<?=table_sort_icons();?></th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <?php
                  if($page_number<2){
                    $row_number=0;
                  }else{                    
                    $row_number=$number_of_records_per_page*($page_number-1);
                  }
                  $product=NULL;
                  foreach ($certificates_of_disinfestation as $certificate_of_disinfestation){
                    $row_background=NULL;                    
                    if($certificate_of_disinfestation->status=="deleting_process"){
                      $row_background="yellow";
                    }elseif($certificate_of_disinfestation->status=="modified"){
                      $row_background="green";
                    }
                    if($certificate_of_disinfestation->certificate_type=="local"){
                      $certificate_type="Внутренний";
                    }elseif($certificate_of_disinfestation->certificate_type=="import"){
                      $certificate_type="Импорт";
                    }elseif($certificate_of_disinfestation->certificate_type=="export"){
                      $certificate_type="Экспорт";
                    }
                    $payment_button_status="unpaid";
                    if(!empty($certificate_of_disinfestation->payment_type)){
                      $payment_button_status="paid";
                    }
                    $row_number++;
                    $country_ru_name=NULL;
                    if($certificate_of_disinfestation->country_id=="0"){
                      $country_ru_name=NULL;
                    }else{                      
                      $country=$country_object->find_by_id($certificate_of_disinfestation->country_id);
                      $country_ru_name=$country->country_ru_name;
                    }
                    $fumigation_declaration=$fumigation_declaration_object->find_by_id($certificate_of_disinfestation->declaration_id);
                    $fumigation_insecticide=$fumigation_insecticide_object->find_by_id($certificate_of_disinfestation->insecticide_id);
                    $formula=$fumigation_formula_object->find_by_id($fumigation_insecticide->fumigation_formula_id)->formula;
                      echo "<tr style='background-color:".$row_background.";'>";
                      echo "<td>".$row_number."</td>";
                      echo "<td><a>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->certificate_number."</a></td>";
                      echo "<td>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->certificate_given_date."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->organization_name."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->organization_inn."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->disinfected_building_name."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".number_format($certificate_of_disinfestation->disinfected_building_volume,3,"."," ")."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->disinfected_building_unit."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$country_ru_name."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$formula."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$fumigation_insecticide->name."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->insecticide_dosage."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".number_format($certificate_of_disinfestation->expended_insecticide_amount,3,"."," ")."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".number_format($fumigation_declaration->price,0,""," ")."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".number_format($certificate_of_disinfestation->total_price,0,""," ")."</td>";
                  ?>  
                <?php
                    echo "<td><a href='print_akt.php?certificate_number=".$certificate_of_disinfestation->certificate_number."'><img src='printer.png' width=25></a></td>";
                    if($certificate_of_disinfestation->status!="deleting_process"){
                ?>
                <td>
                  <a style="display: inline; border:none; padding: 0px;" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_certificate_of_disinfestation<?php echo $certificate_of_disinfestation->id;?>" title='Buzilgan aktni o`chirish.'>
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw text-yellow"></i>
                  </a>
                </td>
                <?php
                    include("../modal/delete_certificate_of_disinfestation.php");
                    }else{
                      echo "<td><a title='Akt ko`rib chiqilmoqda.'><img src='in_process2.png' width=30 ></a></td>"; 
                    }
                    echo "<td>".$certificate_type."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a>".$certificate_of_disinfestation->certificate_number."</a></td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                  }  
                ?>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <?php
            }else{
              echo notification("warning","fa-ban","Ничего не найдено","Предполагается, что у вас нет зарегистрированного акта.");
            }
          ?>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dynamitable.jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">            
          var _gaq = _gaq || [];
          _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-36251023-1']);
          _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'jqueryscript.net']);
          _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);        
          (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
          })();            
        </script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
<?php
  include("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Can i show your home page code ?

Comment: I added my home page cone. Can you check one more time?